# How to add two lists of dictionaries to jsonify?

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 lists full of dictionaries in a FLASK app code. I'd like to return a response of type JSON with the contents of the two lists. 
I'm trying to calculate distances between two locations by their LONGITUDE/LATITUDE properties from an input CSV file, and to respond with a JSON type file filled with the results.
Below is the processing and POST part of the application.
When I run it - I receive a `TypeError : unhashable type: 'list'` on the last line - `return jsonify({points : points, links : links}).`

```
#@app.route("/get_address", methods = ['POST']) 
def process_file(points):

    def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
          points = request.files['file']
          points.save(secure_filename(points.filename))
          return points

    def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
        # approximate radius of earth in mm
        radius = 6371.0 * 1000 
        dlat = radians(lat2-lat1)
        dlon = radians(lon2-lon1)
        a = sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(radians(lat1)) \
            * cos(radians(lat2)) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2)
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
        d = radius * c
        return d    

    points = upload_file()

    with open(points, newline='') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      points = []
      links = []
      for row in reader:  
        p = {"name": list(row.items())[0][1], "address (La/Lo)": (list(row.items())[1][1], list(row.items())[2][1])}    
        points.append(p) 

    l = []
    for point in points:
        for v in point.values():
            l.append(v)

    links = []
    for i in range(0, len(l) -1 , 2):    
        if(i>0):
            for j in range(i-2, 0, -2):
                    links.append({'name': l[i] + l[j], 'distance': calculate_distance(float(l[i+1][0]), float(l[i+1][1]), float(l[j+1][0]), float(l[j+1][1]))})
        else:
            for j in range(i+2, len(l), 2):
                    links.append({'name': l[i] + l[j], 'distance': calculate_distance(float(l[i+1][0]), float(l[i+1][1]), float(l[j+1][0]), float(l[j+1][1]))})

    return jsonify({points : points, links : links})
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys should be strings:

```
return jsonify({"points": points, "links": links})
```

`{points : points, links : links}` would be the right thing in Javascript.

Alternatively you can make a dict with string keys like so:

```
dict(points=points, links=links)
```

According to [the `jsonify` docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify), you can do this directly:

```
return jsonify(points=points, links=links)
```